# Responsive image inside a div, attached to bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I have a header with a menu and an image, I want to position the image like in the following pic:

[image]

The image should be responsive so when i resize my browser it shrinks staying attached to the bottom of the div, overlapping a bit the header.

What should I do to obtain that? I'm using bootstrap for my code.

My code:

```css
.container {
   width: 100%;
}

.container, .con.h {
   background-color: blue;
   height: 100px;
}

.box {
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container .img-logo {
 width: 800px !important;
 position: relative;
 height: auto;
}

.container .img-logo .row {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 50%;
 transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container con-h">
   <div class="row col-md-12">
         Header
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container img-logo">
    <div class="row col-md-12 text-center">
       <div class="box">
             This is the image
         </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Have you tried anything so far? Unfortunately, SO isn't a coding service. Please update your question to show what you have already tried.

Comment: Yeah I tried to put the <img> inside row in a container with position: relative and position: absolute for the image using percents but it doesn't work.

Comment: ok, so share that code in the question

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 0):

You can apply "max-width: 100%" to image or bootstrap giving "img-responsive" class for making image responsive but in bootstrap default class you can not make img in center align but with custom you can make it center possible.

Comment: Img-responsive is ok but i want to overlap thewhite header with the div like in the figure. When I try to overlap it's a mess.